# Get the max not null value from object properties and return properties with similar name

Tags: c#

Consider I have a list of objects with the following class:

```
public Class Example {

int Level1Id {get; private set;}
string Level1Name {get; private set;}
string Level1Description {get; private set;}

int? Level2Id {get; private set;}
string? Level2Name {get; private set;}
string? Level2Description {get; private set;}

int? Level3Id {get; private set;}
string? Level3Name {get; private set;}
string? Level3Description {get; private set;}

int? Level4Id {get; private set;}
string? Level4Name {get; private set;}
string? Level4Description {get; private set;}
}
```

I would like to add a method to this class that will be able to return a tuple containing the id, name and description based on the last not null level property id (i.e. if Level2Id is the last property (for levels) that is not null, this is the max level).

I.e. if I input this

```
Example example = new ()
{
  Level1Id = 10,
  Level2Id = 4,
  Level2Name = "test",
  Level4Id = 1,
  Level4Name = nameof(Level4Description),
  Level4Description = nameof(Level4Description),
};

var output = example.GetMaxLevelData();
Console.WriteLine($"MaxLevelData = {output}");
```

Output

```
MaxLevelData = (1, "Level4Name", "Level4Description")
```

This is a fixed class and I cannot change this due to legacy systems. Reflection seems to be the way to go here, but unclear what would be the *best* way based on the structure we have.

Any advise on this?

Comment: I don't get how you define "may non-null property". How is `1` greater `10`? Or do you mean the max level?

Comment: I am referring to the properties being nullable @MakePeaceGreatAgain

I updated the description

Comment: what if just the description or the name of a group is `null` but the `id` has a value? So what would be the output, if group only had an ID for instance?

Comment: Then the description and name would be null, but this should not be the case on this system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply work backwards with if statements. If your class properties are fixed there's no need to make this complicated with reflection.

```
public (int levelId, string? levelName, string? levelDescription) GetLastSetLevel()
{
    if (this.Level4Id is not null)
    {
        return (this.Level4Id, this.Level4Name, this.Level4Description);
    }

    // repeat if statement for 3 and 2

    return (this.Level1Id, this.Level1Name, this.Level1Description);
}
```

Comment: The only reason why I thought using reflection should be the route to go as there is up to 10 levels. I understand this is still fixed and it would be better to not use reflection for this.